# Haxe - Monitor CPU usage of a particular process/executable

Tags: cpu-usage, profiler, haxe, haxelib

It is required of my Haxe program to calculate the average CPU usage of a particular executable/process over a specified period of time.

I understand that the solution is platform specific and would like to achieve it for both Windows and Linux.